# Not entering in the function

Tags: c++, function, struct

For the last two days I've been trying to wrap up this program, the main thing is that the program itself doesn't go through primercami function when AfegirCamiOrdenat is in the program. Do you have any idea?

```
cami*primercami(cami*primero, int origen){
new cami;
primero->n_aeropuertos=1;
primero->pos_aeropuertos[0]=origen;
primero->coste_acumulado=0;
primero->coste_heuristica=0;
primero->next=NULL;
return primero;
}

cami*AfegirCamiOrdenat (cami* primerolista, cami*nuevoelemento){
cami *ant;
cami *act;
int correcto;
cout<<"Hola estoy ordenando el camino"<<endl;

    if (nuevoelemento == NULL)
    {
        correcto = 0;       //retorna falso si el nuevo elemento no se ha creado bien
    }
    else{                  //si la lista esta vacía el nuevo elemento será el primero
            if(primerolista==NULL)
            {
                primerolista = nuevoelemento;
                primerolista->next = NULL;

    }else                  //busca la posición donde ha de ir el elemento
        {
            ant = NULL;
            act = primerolista;
            while (act->coste_heuristica < nuevoelemento->coste_heuristica && act->next != NULL ) //parar si se llega a la posición donbde insertar o al último elemento
            {
                ant = act;
                act = act->next;
                }
                if (ant == NULL && act->coste_heuristica >= nuevoelemento->coste_heuristica)  //insertar como primer elemento
                    {
                primerolista = nuevoelemento;
                nuevoelemento->next=act;
                }
                else
                    {
                        if (act->next == NULL && act->coste_heuristica<nuevoelemento->coste_heuristica) //insertar como último elemento
                        {
                            act->next=nuevoelemento;
                nuevoelemento->next = NULL;
                }
                else                                //insertar al medio de la lista
                {
                    nuevoelemento->next = act;
                    ant->next=nuevoelemento;
                }
            }
        }
        correcto=1;
    }
    return primerolista;
}
void AEstrella(char lista[24][4], int matPrecio[25][25], int matDist[25][25], int matTiempo[25][25]){
int NumOrigen, NumDestino;
cami*primerelemento;
preguntarVuelo(lista, NumOrigen, NumDestino);
cout<<"El origen es el n "<<NumOrigen<<" y el destino el n "<<NumDestino<<endl;
primerelemento=primercami(primerelemento, NumOrigen);
cout<<"He pasado primercami"<<endl;
while(primerelemento->pos_aeropuertos[primerelemento->n_aeropuertos-1]!=NumDestino){
     cami*expansio;
     cami*expansio2;
     int PosAct=primerelemento->pos_aeropuertos[primerelemento->n_aeropuertos-1];//Determinamos en el APT que nos encontramos
     expansio=primerelemento;
     expansio2=primerelemento;
     expansio->next=NULL;
     expansio2->next=NULL;
     primerelemento=primerelemento->next;
     int Dest1, Dest2;
     mostrarDestinos(vectorVuelos,lista,PosAct,Dest1, Dest2);
     //Expandimos para el primer destino encontrado
     coste_vuelo=matPrecio[PosAct][Dest1];
     heuristica=matPrecio[Dest1][NumDestino];
     ActualitzarCami(expansio, Dest1, coste_vuelo, heuristica);
     cout<<"Coste acumulado: "<<expansio->coste_acumulado<<" Coste heuristica: "<<expansio->coste_heuristica<<endl;
     cout<<"N APTS: "<<expansio->n_aeropuertos<<"  Ultimo APT: "<<expansio->pos_aeropuertos[expansio->n_aeropuertos-1]<<endl;
     primerelemento=AfegirCamiOrdenat(primerelemento, expansio);
     cout<<"Hemos pasado por "<<primerelemento->pos_aeropuertos[0]<<" "<<primerelemento->pos_aeropuertos[1]<<endl;
     //expandimos para el segundo destino encontrado
     coste_vuelo=matPrecio[PosAct][Dest2];
     heuristica=matPrecio[Dest2][NumDestino];
     ActualitzarCami(expansio2, Dest2, coste_vuelo, heuristica);
     primerelemento=AfegirCamiOrdenat(primerelemento, expansio2);

}//while buscando destino
primerelemento=imprimirllistaCami(primerelemento);
esborrarlista(primerelemento);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using a debugger and stepping through the code?  Please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the "main thing" here is that there is no `main`

Comment: The main is not in the post because by the moment the only thing it does is call to void AEstrella, sorry for not saying it in advance.